# Graph of a semi-circle with the diameter

Tags: geometry, functions, analytic-geometry, circles

Rule for the semi-circle that describes the shape of the vertical cross section-section of the dome through its top. The only other information is the diameter which is 43.4m.
The question relates to the Pantheon.

I got $y=\sqrt{21.7^2-x^2}$

Comment: @  Do you want to calculate a length of the semi circle? If so it's $\approx 68.17$m

Comment: I need the rule or equation of the semi-circle.

Comment: It's $\frac{\pi d}{2}.$

Comment: With the origin at $(0,0)$? You should be able to search this up: it is just half a circle. Also, I assume you mean 'vertical' instead of 'verticle'.

Answer (score 1):

If you want an equation of the semi circle without diameter it's
$$y=\sqrt{x(43.4-x)}.$$
An equation of the semi circle with diameter:
$$y\left(y-\sqrt{x(43.4-x)}\right)=0.$$

Comment: I assume you don't need the $\sqrt y - \sqrt y$?

Comment: I got y=√(21.7²-x²)

Comment: @sjdw03 where the point $(0,0)$?

Comment: @Toby Mak You are right! We can write it without $\sqrt{y}-\sqrt{y}.$ I fixed. Thank you!